# How to disable scrolling in NSScrollView with enabled responsive scrolling

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-sierra, nsscrollview, scrollwheel

I need to disable programmatically scrolling in `NSSrollView` with enabled responsive scrolling.

I try override `isCompatibleWithResponsiveScrolling`, then is possible to override `scrollWheel` and have enabled responsive scrolling but `scrollWheel` works different in that implementation. Is called only once, on start of scroll but I want to break scroll that is in progress.

It's possible to do this in different way that not need to override `scrollWheel` method?

Comment: What do you mean by responsive scrolling? As in getting calls when a scroll view is scrolled (but not actually scrolling?)

Comment: About responsive scrolling https://gist.github.com/zwaldowski/8710fddc8b0b39d2c152#10_9Scrolling.
Yes, only when start scroll.